# Why Event Trigger in Unity dont execute command on my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

Don't work EventTrigger,but Event System be on scene
Unity:
[image]

Code:
[image]

Project:
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Fevl4hXCER8ZyQ

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Comment: But the debug shows speed of 1. In button test you set it to 1. That looks like it worked to me

Comment: I tested work function ButtonTest,speed = 1 because i pressed key on "Horizontal",but not click on object

Comment: Does your car have a collider?

Comment: No,i test this now

Comment: With collider no work

Answer (score 0):

Event triggers only work with images that are inside a canvas. you are currently using a Sprite that corresponds to a unity 2D object for that you use the physics and functions of unity 2D RigidBody2D, boxCollider2D, CircleCollider and Etc... by doing this you have access to functions like OnTriggerEnter2D , OnTriggerExit2D, onMouseEnter, and among others .

if what you want is to make a button use the Canvas elements and enter the buttons, images and others inside, these elements that are inside the canvas or the UnityEngine.UI namespace you can use the EventTrigger